# Given that $\sum_{n}^{\infty} a_n$ is convergent, is $\sum_{n}^{\infty} n^n a_n$ convergent?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, proof-writing

Given that $\sum_{n}^{\infty} a_n$ is convergent, non-negative series, I have to find out if $\sum_{n}^{\infty} n^n a_n$ is convergent or divergent.

Since $\sum_{n}^{\infty} a_n$ is a "non-negative" series, $a_n \geq 0$ for all $n$ and I cannot use ratio test (since it requires all terms to be >0).

I am considering using limit comparison test but am struggling since all the series I took eventually has a limit 0 and I cannot conclude anything.

Comment: The best way to proves that one of those series diverges, is to think of an example that clearly diverges. Look at 1. for example. How fast does n^n grow? Pretty dang fast! Pick some a_n that we know converges and use something like the root test to show we have an issue. Hint for 3. Alternating series test.

Comment: I was thinking Alternating series test for 3), but my main concern was that I was stuck how to prove that the sequence a_n is decreasing. Do you have any hints on that? thank you so much!!

Comment: Can $a_n$ be increasing if $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{a_n}$ exists?

Answer (score 1):

Counter-example for 1): $a_n=\frac 1 {n^{n+1}}$. Note that $a_n \leq \frac 1 {n^{2}}$.

Counter-example  for 3): $a_n=0$ for $n$ odd and $a_n=\frac  1 {n^{2}}$ for $n$ even.

The series in 2) is convergent: Use the fact that $\ln (1+x) \sim  x$ to compare the series with $\sum \frac {a_{n+1}-a_n} {2+a_n}$. This series is absolutely convergent since $2+a_n \to 2$ and $|a_{n+1}-a_n| \leq a_{n+1}+a_n$.